# "É claro que tu és contra a pena de morte. O estupro ocorreu com a minha filha, não com a tua." What kind of rhetorical device or fallacy is this?

Tags: figuras-de-linguagem

A similar "use of words" would be

> "Eu não esperava mesmo que tu fosses votar a favor do aborto. Tu não és mulher e não tens a menor idéia de como uma gravidez indesejada provoca sofrimento"

What do we call this fallacy, this rhetorical device, in Portuguese?

Comment: Fallacious reasoning is not a question about Portuguese. It can happen in any language.

Comment: @Lambie  Adjectives and conjunctions also happen in any language. So does passive vocabulary.  Figures of speech and fallacies are an essential chapter in the study of any language. In Portugal and in Brazil they are included in the syllabus plan of every high school, and the students learn their names, definitions and examples. If I ask you if there is any figure of speech and what it is called, in "Aquele cara é um armário.Tu não podes com ele", **it is** a question about Portuguese Language. The moderators and the community will decide whether this is off-topic.  Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: Fallacious reasoning is not the subject matter of a language forum per se. A figure of speech and a fallacy are not in the same category of knowledge.

Comment: @Centaurus maybe you could rephrase the question to focus more explicitly on "how can I say <concept> in Portuguese?" (like if you would ask e.g. "how do I call an Aardvark in Portuguese?" or "what is the Portuguese word for when you miss someone?") - which seems to be a more direct, clear, and on-topic way of phrasing the question. That is what you are asking, is it not?

Comment: @ANeves    Assim como as figuras de linguagem (metáforas, pleonasmos, elipses, hipérboles, etc,) as figuras de retórica também tem sua classificação (o apelo ao ridículo, o apelo à emoção, o espantalho, o apelo a tradição, o clamando pela questão, a generalização apressada, o envenenamento do poço, o Red Herring, o Ad Logicam, o apelo a ignorancia, só para citar alguns)  É a isso que se refere a minha pergunta.  Que tipo de falácia ou figura de retórica está sendo usada nas frases acima.

Comment: @ANeves  Fiquei em dúvida se trata-se de um apelo à ignorância, uma generalização apressada, um envenamento do poço, ou outro tipo.

Comment: Who says this is any kind of fallacy or rhetorical device? You have not shown that it is. It is merely an opinion.

Comment: @Lambie I have answered it myself and shown what rhetorical device it is.  There are references too, to back up what you say is just an opinion.

Comment: No, you provide two translations into Portuguese. You do **not show** that the English contains a rhetorical device or fallacy. You have to show it, prove it.

Comment: @Lambie   A pergunta é sobre língua portuguesa.  Não tenho que mostrar ou provar que há um falácia em Inglês.  O termo que se usa em português é **"envenenando o poço"**.  Deixei 4 referências para os possíveis céticos de plantão.  Considero o assunto encerrado.

Comment: Não, senhor. A pergunta é sobre a retórica. O fato de ser em português não tem nada a ver. Poderia ter feito a mesma pergunta em inglês. Parece que você não entende a diferença entre língua e retórica. Ha ha: Poisoning the well (or attempting to poison the well) is a type of informal fallacy where adverse information about a target is preemptively presented to an audience, with the intention of discrediting or ridiculing something that the target person is about to say. Wikipedia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Envenenando o poço**

> - **Poisoning the well** (or attempting to poison the well) is a fallacy where irrelevant adverse information about a target is preemptively presented to an audience, with the intention of discrediting or ridiculing everything that the target person is about to say. Poisoning the well can be a special case of argumentum ad hominem, and the term was first used with this sense by John Henry Newman in his work Apologia Pro Vita Sua (1864).[1] The origin of the term lies in well poisoning, an ancient wartime practice of pouring poison into sources of fresh water before an invading army, to diminish the attacking army's strength. [**from Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_the_well)
> - **Envenenando o poço ou Envenenamento do poço** (em inglês: Poisoning the well), ou tentativa de envenenar o poço, é um dispositivo retórico em que informações adversas sobre um alvo são preventivamente apresentadas a uma audiência, com a intenção de desacreditar ou de ridicularizar tudo o que aquela pessoa tem a dizer. Envenenando o poço pode ser considerado um caso especial de argumentum ad hominem. Através desta falácia coloca-se o oponente em uma posição na qual ele fica incapaz de responder. --- [**from Wikipedia pt**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envenenando_o_po%C3%A7o)

**Examples**

- "Antes que os senhores ouçam o discurso do meu oponente, quero lembrar que **ele já esteve preso**"
- "É óbvio que você apoia a proposta do prefeito, **vocês são da mesma igreja**; de que lado você ficaria?"
- "Meritíssimo, não há prova alguma contra o meu cliente, e **a única testemunha é uma prostituta.**"
- "Minha proposta de construir uma creche neste local é para favorecer muitas crianças. Qualquer um que se oponha **certamente odeia crianças**.

> Duas pessoas se encontram na rua. Uma pergunta à outra:
>
> - Bom dia. Poderia me dizer onde fica a taverna do Sr. X? Dizem que ele serve um ótimo vinho.
> - Ah, cuidado com aquele pilantra. Ele é todo atencioso, vai te oferecer uns amendoins de graça, te colocar numa mesa bem arejada, tudo isso prá vender mais caro um vinho que tem mais fama do que sabor. É o primeiro estabelecimento da próxima rua, mas fique atento.
>
> Apesar do estranhamento e da inquietação, o primeiro sujeito vai à tal taverna, e encontra, de fato, tudo conforme foi dito pelo mal-humorado transeunte: uma recepção calorosa, uma mesa bastante limpa, uns acepipes de cortesia... Nosso amigo saiu correndo do estabelecimento antes mesmo de ver a carta de vinhos. Todo satisfeito, o interlocutor dispara uma sonora gargalhada e diz:
>
> - “Eu não te disse?”.
>
> Não sabemos qual foi a motivação do detrator, se é um concorrente, se há algum problema pessoal, se ele é contrário a bebidas alcoólicas. O fato é que ele aplicou uma manipulação psicológica que deu certo, porque narrou uma sequência verídica que se confirmou de início, mas que não foi levada a cabo para averiguação da verdade. Esse é o truque da falácia do poço envenenado – ela não mente necessariamente, mas tenta enganar sempre.

Referências:

- 1 https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envenenando_o_po%C3%A7o
- 2 http://falaciasonline.wikidot.com/envenenando-o-poco
- 3 http://filosofia-mitologia.blogspot.com.br/p/dicto-simpliciter-quer-dizer-um.html
- 4 http://plethos.blogspot.com.br/2015/02/pequeno-guia-das-grandes-falacias-8.html

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It is easier to prejudge someone beforehand rather than to put yourself in this person's shoes.

Long answer:
I see this as a scenario where some A dude/dudette would try to argue with some one about one idea/case/occurrence which is totally away from his/her reality, maybe giving little credit for whom is defending a cause (in this case, the right of abortion).

As cliché as it could sound, try to imagine, say for this example, a white rich studied average person who doesn't run into too much trouble in his/her life and has family support and so on..., only prejudging some poor woman who wants to have such right of abortion, yet the other persons knows nothings about what the life of such woman could be and still tries to complain without having real understanding of such situation, only because it is simple to judge someone rather to be on someone's shoes.

Comment: If you feel more comfortable writing in Portuguese, feel free to do it. Most of us will understand you.  Still, you don't seem to be giving an answer to the question.

Comment: Was my English bad? :(

Comment: In any case, I believe the fallacy here is that someone how have been victim of something will have (potentially) a point of view way different from who does not agree with him/her.
For the case, it may be easy to someone whose daughter have not been assaulted to be against the death penalty in contrast with some one whose daughter had suffered such a misfortune and by turn advocated in favour of the death penalty. I hope I have made myself clearer here.

Comment: Your English is not bad, Reuel. But **how is it called, or explained, in Portuguese**? If Centaurus just wanted to understand the fallacy, he would post in Portuguese; or he would post in English, but in elu.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Ohhhh, I see....Thanks for pointing it out @ANeves. Sorry Centaurus, I misunderstood the question. I tried searching for a label/name for this situation, but I could not find any one that would suit this case. In any case, in [wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fal%C3%A1cia) we can find a very long list of fallacy denominations. You might be interested to give it a look. It may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Não sou especialista mas esta é uma questão interessante e sobre a qual quero brevemente dissertar. Talvez ajude.

Será que um homem pode ter noção de quanto sofrimento provoca uma gravidez indesejada? Eu diria que sim. De forma talvez um pouco simplista: um homem não carrega o feto e não terá, por isso, a dor física de ter uma gravidez (para simplificar, deixemos o campo espiritual de parte). No entanto, o homem sofre as consequências como a mulher: dispêndio de tempo, energia, dinheiro, entre outros. Ele sofrerá psicologicamente tal como a mulher. Este sofrimento psicológico é frequentemente bem pior do que qualquer sofrimento físico. Com base nisto, poderia dizer-se que se trata de uma simples **falsa analogia**: o facto de ele ser homem não tem a ver com desconhecer o sofrimento e, daí, estar contra o aborto. São factos sem relação.

Comment: Vítor, uma outra falácia bem semelhante seria: "Meritíssimo, não há nenhuma evidência concreta de que meu cliente tenha cometido o crime. *Além disso, a única testemunha apresentada é uma prostituta.*"  Não creio que se trate de "falsa analogia".